# Cannot interpret SVM model using Shapash

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, shap, xai

Currently, I'm exploring machine learning interpretability tools for one of my project. I found Shapash quite a new tool and many people suggesting to use it to create a few easily interpretable charts for ML model. When I tried it with RandomForestClassifier it worked fine and generate a webpage full of different charts but the same I cannot achieve while using SVM(just exploring this library, not focusing on the perfect ML model for a problem).

Note - using Shapash [link here](https://github.com/MAIF/shapash)

```
#Fit blackbox model
svc = svm.SVC()
svc.fit(X_train_smote, y_train_smote)
y_pred = svc.predict(X_test)
print(f"F1 Score {f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro')}")
print(f"Accuracy {accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)}")
```

```
from shapash import SmartExplainer
```

```
xpl = SmartExplainer(model=svc)
```

error which I'm getting -

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_13648/1233939729.py in <module>
----> 1 xpl = SmartExplainer(model=svc)

~/Python_AI/ai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shapash/explainer/smart_explainer.py in __init__(self, model, backend, preprocessing, postprocessing, features_groups, features_dict, label_dict, title_story, palette_name, colors_dict, **kwargs)
    194         if isinstance(backend, str):
    195             backend_cls = get_backend_cls_from_name(backend)
--> 196             self.backend = backend_cls(
    197                 model=self.model, preprocessing=preprocessing, **kwargs)
    198         elif isinstance(backend, BaseBackend):

~/Python_AI/ai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shapash/backend/shap_backend.py in __init__(self, model, preprocessing, explainer_args, explainer_compute_args)
     16         self.explainer_args = explainer_args if explainer_args else {}
     17         self.explainer_compute_args = explainer_compute_args if explainer_compute_args else {}
---> 18         self.explainer = shap.Explainer(model=model, **self.explainer_args)
     19 
     20     def run_explainer(self, x: pd.DataFrame) -> dict:

~/Python_AI/ai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shap/explainers/_explainer.py in __init__(self, model, masker, link, algorithm, output_names, feature_names, **kwargs)
    166                 # if we get here then we don't know how to handle what was given to us
    167                 else:
--> 168                     raise Exception("The passed model is not callable and cannot be analyzed directly with the given masker! Model: " + str(model))
    169 
    170             # build the right subclass

Exception: The passed model is not callable and cannot be analyzed directly with the given masker! Model: SVC()
```

Comment: What is your `scikit-learn` version?

Comment: scikit-learn==1.1.1

Comment: I think the error message tells you to use `predict` or some similar method

Comment: Can you give me a sample code to use svc with shapash?

Comment: I suggest you first try and understand how `svc `works with `shap` and then detour to more esoteric packages

Comment: SVM - long time not seen! SHAP values are calculated from numeric predictions, but your model is a classification model.